# Collation Conflict for substring operation on Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000, substring, conflict, collation

I have created a view in a SQL Server 2000 (v8.0.760) which joins several tables with outer joins and uses ISNULL, REPLACE, and SUBSTRING functions.  The view works fine on that database.  The database is set for collation Latin1_General_BIN.

However, when I try to access that data via a linked server on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, with the same collation, fails with the following error:

> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   Msg 446, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   Cannot resolve collation conflict for substring operation.

I have tried several things including setting collate on the substring fields on my view, setting linked server options Collation Compatibility = True and Collation Name = 'blank', as well as others.

I can select data via the linked server from other tables/views.  The view SQL to create the view is:

```
SELECT 'CRM' AS SYSTEM_SOURCE,
  ISNULL(F.PARENT_REGION_ID,' ') AS REGION, 
  ISNULL(B.COMPANYID,' ') AS COMPANYID, 
  ISNULL(A.SO_ID,' ') AS SO_ID,
  ISNULL(L.LINE_NBR,0) AS TIMESHEET_LINE, 
  isnull(H.NOTE_SEQ_NBR,0) AS NOTE_SEQ_NBR, 
  ISNULL(A.SERVICE_ID,' ') AS SERVICE_ID, 
  ISNULL(C.DESCR80,' ') AS DESCR80, 
  ISNULL(A.SO_STATUS,' ') AS SO_STATUS, 
  ISNULL(A.SO_PRIORITY,' ') AS SO_PRIORITY, 
  ISNULL(E.ASSETTAG,' ') AS ASSETTAG,
  ISNULL(RIGHT(REPLICATE(' ', 18) + LTRIM(E.INST_PROD_ID), 18),' ') AS PRODUCT_ID, 
  ISNULL(G.NAME1,' ') AS NAME1, 
  ISNULL((CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.SO_DATE,121)),'') AS SO_DATE, 
  ISNULL((CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.START_DT,121)),'') AS ACTL_START_DATE, 
  ISNULL((CONVERT(CHAR(10),D.ACT_END_DATE,121)),'') AS ACTL_END_DATE, 
  ISNULL(A.ENS_MTR_TOTAL,0) AS ENS_MTR_TOTAL, 
  ISNULL(K.ENS_MTR_READING,0) AS ENS_MTR_READING, 
  ISNULL(I.ENS_MTR_TOTAL,0) AS ENS_MTR_TOTAL, 
  ISNULL(D.TOTAL_ACT_TIME,0) AS TOTAL_ACT_TIME, 
  ISNULL(A.ENS_IPROD_DWN_TIME,0) AS ENS_IPROD_DWN_TIME, ISNULL(A.ENS_RIG_DWN_TIME,0) AS ENS_RIG_DWN_TIME, 
  ISNULL(J.MODEL_NBR,' ') AS MODEL_NBR, ISNULL(J.PROD_BRAND,' ') AS PROD_BRAND,
  ISNULL((CONVERT(CHAR(10),E.INSTALLED_DATE,121)),'') AS INSTALLED_DATE, 
  ISNULL(L.PERSON_ID, ' ') AS PERSON_ID, 
  ISNULL(L.DTL_TOTAL, 0) AS DTL_TOTAL, 
  ISNULL(SUBSTRING(D.ENS_PROBLEM_CD, 1, 15),' ') as PROBLEM_CD, 
  ISNULL(SUBSTRING(D.ENS_PRDCOMP_ID, 1, 15),' ') as PROBLEM_ID,
  CASE
     WHEN L.PERSON_ID = NULL THEN ' '
  ELSE ISNULL((SELECT M.NAME FROM PS_RD_PERSON_NAME M WHERE M.PERSON_ID = L.PERSON_ID), ' ') END AS NAME,
  (CONVERT(CHAR(10),SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10),121)) AS CUR_DATE,
  ISNULL(REPLACE(H.SUMMARY_RF,'|',''),' ') AS NOTE_SUBJECT , 
  ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(H.DESCRLONG AS CHAR(8000)), CHAR(10),' '), CHAR(13), ' '),'|', ''),' ') AS NOTE_DETAIL 
  FROM PS_RF_SO_HDR A
     , PS_RD_COMPANY B
     , PS_RF_SERVICE C
     , PS_RF_SO_LINE D 
     , PS_RB_REGION F
     , PS_RF_PROVIDER_GRP G
     , PS_RF_INST_PROD E
     , PS_RF_SO_NOTE H
     , PS_ENS_MTR_INST_PR I
     , PS_PROD_ITEM J
     , PS_ENS_MTR_SO_HDR K
     , PS_RF_TIME_LINE L
  WHERE A.BO_ID_CUST = B.BO_ID 
     AND C.SERVICE_ID = A.SERVICE_ID 
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.SO_ID = D.SO_ID 
     AND B.COMPANYID *= F.REGION_ID 
     AND A.PROVIDER_GRP_ID *=G.PROVIDER_GRP_ID
     AND A.INST_PROD_ID *= E.INST_PROD_ID 
     AND A.SO_ID *=H.SO_ID --AND 1 = '1' 
     AND A.INST_PROD_ID *= I.INST_PROD_ID 
     AND A.CUST_SETID *= J.SETID 
     AND A.PRODUCT_ID *= J.PRODUCT_ID 
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = K.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND A.SO_ID = K.SO_ID 
     AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT *= L.BUSINESS_UNIT 
     AND D.TIME_SHEET_ID *= L.TIME_SHEET_ID
```

Comment: Really... That is all you have to offer?

Answer (score 1):

"Put some effort into reducing your query" ?

I'm sorry, you truly have no cognitive understanding of the fact that we do NOT know what the functional requirements of this query is.  The functional requirements alone dictate the development effort, that is, unless you are saying his skill in writing SQL is insufficient.  Funny, you offered no truly constructive criticism that shows you have a better understanding of this situation than he does and the code necessary to complete his SQL. No magic bullet fix to correct his problem.  Instead, you insult his expertise.

But wait, you don't know the functional requirements, do you?

Perhaps when you can actually offer something that is a useful response, it would be more welcome.  In the meanwhile, get a few years under your belt, junior.  Get back to me when you're truly dealing with multi-million row enterprise level corporate databases as a developer.  Than I'm sure you'll be far less likely to criticize with such a snarky answer as what you have provided above.

Yours truly,

Flynn Kinkade